# Error when trying to use both mongo and sql jpa in the same spring app

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-boot, intellij-idea

We have a spring app that works with mongodb.
Now we need it to connect also to mysql.

All the beans are defined in a applicationContext.xml legacy file.

We like that the new mysql configuration will be in java classes.

We created an entity, repository and a configuraion java files.

But it seems that as we try to do so, spring gets confused.

If we try to run the app,  it start complaining about the **mongo** repositories:

```
Error creating bean with name 'MyMongoRepository': Could not resolve matching constructor (hint: specify index/type/name arguments for simple parameters to avoid type ambiguities
```

In the intellij we have the "could not autowire" error only on the sql repository (the first 3 are the mongo repositories):

[image]

Is it possible that the @configuration class is clashing with the applicationContext?

Should the @configuraion class be in a certain package/folder to work correctly?

Also, in the @configuration file, as there are green beans on the left side, it seems like intellij is able to understand where is the persistence repository.

[image]

Thanks for any help.

Comment: have you defined the datasource in application.properties file for mysql?

Comment: yes, we have defined an  application.properties file: `hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create-drop
hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy=org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy
hibernate.show_sql=false
hibernate.format_sql=true


spring.datasource.url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/myDataBase
spring.datasource.username=user
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver`

Comment: if you have defined datasource then jpa would inherit the properties from there, can you also make sure that the application.properties is in the correct path. `src/main/resources `

Comment: yes, it is in src/main/resources. In the intellij I also able to navigate to the relevant field in the properties files from the class when crtl+click the name of the property (e.g. username)